# The position of the footer should be identical for all displays

Tags: html, css, footer

#### Introduction

The position of the footer should be adjusted for different monitors so that the footer is displayed in the same place on all monitors as it is on the others.

#### Problem

In my research I got nowhere and only found answers that define how a footer is developed. May also be because my research was not correct.

#### Source code

```
<footer class="pr-2 s bg-indigo-lightest-10">
    <div class="flex flex-wrap mt-10">
        <div class="md-br-l-10">
            <div class="white opacity-100 mt-l1">
               <p style=" position: relative; "> 2021 Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: use `position:fixed` property to keep it fixed in the same place of the screen. Check this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fixed_footer.asp

Comment: try googling 'sticky footer': that may help